# Getting error while deploying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, rubygems

I'm deploying my rails application and when reading gemfile getting error :

**Could not find responders-2.1.0 in any of the sources**

Comment: We need much more information than this. Where are you deploying to? What does your gemfile look like? Does it work locally?

Comment: i'm deploying on aws using 'cap'

Comment: @raghavvishnoi - Please show your gemfile. Are you able o trun `bundle install` locally?

Comment: The problem is that your production environment doesn't have the `responders` gem installed: that's what the error is telling you.  Often, your deploy process would automatically install any required gems, eg using Bundler.  So, either yours ISN'T doing this, or it's trying to but failing for some reason.  You will need to provide more info, eg your deploy script, and the full stack trace, in order for people to try to diagnose the underlying cause of the error.  Please add any futher info in **an edit to your question, not comments**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27412638/why-does-rails-4-2-responders-keeps-telling-me-to-add-responders-to-the-gemfil