# respond_with in Rails 5 API-only app (and responder gem) always returns blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, actioncontroller, rails-api, ruby-on-rails-5

Has anyone else come across this? I'm writing a Rails API in Rails 5 (`5.0.0.beta2`), and have included the `responder` gem so as to be able to use `respond_with`, and put `respond_to :json` in the controller, but no matter what I pass to `respond_with` (e.g. `respond_with @collection`), the response is always blank. Anyone know why this might happen?

Comment: did you add `respond_to :json` to your controller?

Comment: @OlegSobchuk Ooh, good catch. I have, but I should've mentioned that in the question.

Answer (score 1):

`responders 2.1.2` includes a fix for `ActionController::API`, update your app

Answer (score 0):

have you tried responding in the controller with something like:

render :json => { data: "Success!" }

or if you're in a respond_to block, something like:

format.json { render json: "Success!" }

Comment: Yes, those work fine. Unfortunately, the reason I want to be using `respond_with` is that my goal is to render the json via the `trailblazer` gem, which implicitly uses a call to `respond_with` for this.

Comment: gotcha. not familiar with that gem. have you tried passing a block to respond_with similar to what you might do with respond_to?

      respond_with(project, task, status: 201) do |format|

Comment: Yeah. The status codes do make it through, but the content is always blank.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46554377/8518019

steps: 
1. add to gemfile 
gem 'responder', '~> 2.0'

2. rails generate responder:install
3. rails generate scaffold ....
4. I suggest running rake db:drop. db:create then rake db:migrate (I am pretty early on in my app so my database wasnt something i was concerned about deleting and re-creating)
5. It worked for me after I included the gemfiles before i created the scaffold hope this helps